# Custom widget does not appear on Main Window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I've trying to create a custom widget and make it appear on Grid Layout on the main window.

```
class MyCustomWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCustomWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.testText = QtGui.QLabel()
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.testText.setFont(font)
        self.testText.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.testText.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("patientText"))
        self.testText.setText("Test")

class UIMainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        ...
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        ...

        self.test = MyCustomWidget()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.test)
```

When I run this code, main window appears but there is nothing about the widget that I created. If I simply add an QLabel to grid layout, it appears.

Comment: You are not adding any `MyCustomWidget` to your main window.

Comment: @fferri I've changed my code in order to make it clear. But I forgot to change one line which is self.test = MyCustomWidget()

Comment: try `self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)` in `setupUi` method of `UIMainWindow` class

Comment: Actually since `UIMainWindow` does not inherit from a widget class, I guess you need to do `MainWindow.addLayout(self.gridLayout)`

Comment: @ValentinB. Grid layout isn't the root layout in my project. But I am sure it's visible on screen. Because If I add another widget like QLabel etc. to that grid layout , it appears on screen.

Comment: Have you tried displaying your custom widget without embedding it in a layout ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried. How will I do that?

Comment: Actually I've just re-read your code, I think you're going at it wrong: `MyCustomWidget` should inherit directly from `QLabel`. Then inside its `setupUi` you should call method directly on `self`.

Comment: Try `self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.test.testText)` if it works I am probably right.

Comment: @ValentinB. If I knew this widget will simply be derivative of QLabel, I would do it as you said. But I'm planning this widget to contain multiple widgets.

Comment: Then you widget should contain a layout, and you need to add your sub-widgets to that layout !

Comment: As you said I tried self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.test.testText) and it worked. But how will I add widget itself completely?

Comment: Ohhh, I just get it. Can you post it as an answer so I accept it as solution? Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome ! GUI can be confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is, your `MyCustomWidget` is simply a standard widget with an attribute `testText` containing a `QLabel`. If you want it to contain subwidgets that will show on your main window, you need to instantiate a layout, add the sub widgets to the layout, then add the layout to `MyCustomWidget`:

*At the end of MyCustomWidget's setupUi*

```
self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MyCustomWidgetLayout"))

self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.testText)

#add all other widgets here

self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
```

You can also create embedded layouts, by calling `addLayout` method on the parent layout and passing it the child layout !