# PyQt5 - Custom widgets open in separate windows rather than in same window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph, custom-widgets

I'm new at PyQt, and I'm trying to create a main window containing two custom widgets, the first being a data grapher, the second being a QGridLayout containing QLabels. Problem is: the two widgets open in separate windows and have no content.

I've found multiple posts with a similar problem:

- [PyQt5 Custom Widget Opens in Another Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70445471/pyqt5-custom-widget-opens-in-another-window)
- [Custom widget does not appear on Main Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50061518/custom-widget-does-not-appear-on-main-window)
- [PyQt5 Custom Widget Opens in Another Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70445471/pyqt5-custom-widget-opens-in-another-window)
- And even a FAQ on this specific problem: https://www.pythonguis.com/faq/pyqt-widgets-appearing-as-separate-windows/

But I haven't been able to figure out why my code doesn't work. My aim is to obtain a result as shown below on the left, but instead I'm getting a result as shown on the right:

[image]

My code is the following (can be copied and run as it is):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg


class CustomWidget_1(QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
      super(CustomWidget_1, self).__init__()
      self.channels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
      self.win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(title='Plot', size=(800, 600))
      self.plots = list()
      self.curves = list()
      for i in range(len(self.channels)):
         p = self.win.addPlot(row=i, col=0)
         p.showAxis('left', False)
         p.setMenuEnabled('left', False)
         p.showAxis('bottom', False)
         p.setMenuEnabled('bottom', False)
         self.plots.append(p)
         curve = p.plot()
         self.curves.append(curve)
      self.win.show()
      print('CustomWidget_1 initialized.')

class CustomWidget_2(QWidget):
   def __init__(self, labelnames):
      super(CustomWidget_2, self).__init__()
      self.grid = QGridLayout()
      self.labelnames = labelnames
      self.qlabels = []
      for label in self.labelnames:
         labelBox = QLabel(label)
         labelBox.setFont(QFont('Arial', 16))
         labelBox.setStyleSheet('border: 2px solid black;')
         labelBox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
         self.qlabels.append(labelBox)
         index = self.labelnames.index(label)
         q, r = divmod(index, 6)
         self.grid.addWidget(labelBox, q, r)
      print('CustomWidget_2 initialized.')


class MainWindow(QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
      super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

      self.labelnames = ['label 1', 'label 2', 'label 3']
      
      self.CustomWidget_1 = CustomWidget_1()
      self.CustomWidget_1.setParent(self)
      self.CustomWidget_1.show()

      self.CustomWidget_2 = CustomWidget_2(self.labelnames)
      self.CustomWidget_2.setParent(self)
      self.CustomWidget_2.show()

      self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
      self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.CustomWidget_1)
      self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.CustomWidget_2)
      self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

      self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   predictVisualizer = MainWindow()
   sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I could fix it? Any pointers towards tutorials and/or templates would be greatly appreciated as well! Thanks!

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code, but the most important is that it does *not* reflect the image (most importantly, labels are not shown, because in the code the layout is never set). In any case, if you want multiple widgets in a main window, create a QWidget as a container, set a layout for it, add the widgets to the layout, and finally call `setCentralWidget()` with the container above. Note that it's also unclear what `CustomWidget_1` should do, since actually showing the `win` member. Remove the `setParent()` calls, as they're useless if you properly use layout managers.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to set up the multi-widget system following your instructions and changing CustomWidget_1 and CustomWidget_2 to QLabels('text'), to test it out. But when I use the original custom widgets, nothing is displayed inside the main window. How do I make the widgets actually 'show up' once I've added them to the container layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should write fewer lines of code and debug slowly, if you are new to pyqt5 you should read carefully the basic Layout creation, like you are creating a website interface, link: https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyqt-layouts/

This is the code I have edited, you can can refer:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize,Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget,QGridLayout,QVBoxLayout,QLabel,QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPalette, QColor

class CustomWidget_1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,color):
        super(CustomWidget_1, self).__init__()
        
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(400,300))
        
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(color))
        self.setPalette(palette)        

class CustomWidget_2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,color):
        super(CustomWidget_2, self).__init__()
        
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(400,134))
        layout.setContentsMargins(70,0,0,0)
        
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(color))
        self.setPalette(palette)
        
        Label1 = QLabel()
        Label1.setText('abc')
        Label2 = QLabel()
        Label2.setText('sad')
        Label3 = QLabel()
        Label3.setText('qv')        
        layout.addWidget(Label1)
        layout.addWidget(Label2)
        layout.addWidget(Label3)
  
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        layout.addWidget(CustomWidget_1("blue"))
        layout.addWidget(CustomWidget_2("red"))

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```